# Patent validity - Can it be used freely?

Tags: validity

Thank you for this forum with lots of great information.

I did a patent search registered under the number:
Legal status of EP1020844 (A2) 2000-07-19; [EP1020844 (A3)](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP1020844A3/en?oq=EP1020844) 2004-04-28

A priori the patent is free of rights (validity 20 years) but I note that modifications have been made during the period. Does this mean that there is an extension of the validity period of this patent?

I sent an email to the EPO department, so far no feedback.

If anyone can give me expert help regarding this patent and rights.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure validity is what you are questioning. Perhaps freedom to operate?

Comment: I'm sorry the lack of expertise in the matter makes me poorly expressed and therefore understand.  Absolutely, in fact I want to know if we can freely use the model protected by this patent or not?!

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [EP1020844 (A3)'s](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?II=0&ND=3&adjacent=true&locale=en_EP&FT=D&date=20000719&CC=EP&NR=1020844A2&KC=A2) priority date is 01/16/1999. Issued patents generally are in force for 20 years from their priority date. Looking at the INPADOC legal status page, the last entry from 2008/03/07 states:

"STATUS: THE APPLICATION IS DEEMED TO BE WITHDRAWN".

This suggests the application was never granted as a patent. Even if it did, we are more than 20 years from the priority date.

I am not a lawyer and this is not a legal opinion. You would be best served getting a formal freedom to operate opinion. Also, please keep in mind that while this patent application may not be in force, there is always the potential for other relevant patents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for tour answer!Can you please explain to me exactly what you mean by « Also, please keep in mind that while this patent application may not be in force, there is always the potential for other relevant patents »

Comment: @TOPREFEREE What I mean is that avoiding one doesn’t mean you avoid all patents. It’s a good idea to do a thorough patent search to make sure there isn’t some problematic patent out there.

Comment: Thank you very very much!